# Codeigniter - Receiving Email but not receiving message which I send in Email

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-2

I am working on sending the email in loop in codeigniter.
    What actually happening is I am receveing the email but it doest not shwing the message which I had included. Following is script:

```
    <?php

    Class Email extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function index()
        {

            $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'myemail',
                'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
                'send_multipart' => FALSE
            );
            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->load->database();
                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT email FROM users');


            // $this->email->initialize($config);    
            // $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');



                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                       $this->email->clear();

                       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");   
                       $this->load->library('email',$config);




                       $this->email->from("mymail","myname");


                        $this->email->to($row->email);
                        $this->email->subject("THIS IS AN EMAIL TEST");
                        $this->email->message('Hello, We are <strong>Example Inc.</strong>');
                        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                        if($this->email->send())
                        {
                            echo "Your Mail send";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                        }
                }

                echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();





        }
    }

?>
```

I am expecting `Hello, We are <strong>Example Inc.</strong>'` this message in email but what I actually getting is

[image]

No mesage in email. Where I am making mistake.

Comment: remove `html` tags and check. remove`<strong></strong>`

Comment: Removing html tag does not works. If I am passing any page template stores in view folder then its working fine. But if I am passing string as message in `message()` its not working. is `send_multipart` is false thats why its happening?

Comment: remove this code from inside the foreach loop $this->load->library('email',$config); as you are already loading email library outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this

```
<?php

    Class Email extends CI_Controller
    {
        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        function index()
        {

            $config = Array(
                'protocol' => 'smtp',
                'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                'smtp_port' => 465,
                'smtp_user' => 'myemail',
                'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
                'mailtype'  => 'html', 
                'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1',
                'send_multipart' => FALSE
            );
            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->load->database();
                $query = $this->db->query('SELECT email FROM users');


            // $this->email->initialize($config);    
            // $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');



                foreach ($query->result() as $row)
                {
                       $this->email->clear();

                       $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");   
                       $this->load->library('email',$config);

                        $message = '<html><body>';
                        $message .= 'Hello, We are <strong>Example Inc.</strong>';


                       $this->email->from("mymail","myname");


                        $this->email->to($row->email);
                        $this->email->subject("THIS IS AN EMAIL TEST");
                        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                        $this->email->message($message); 

                        if($this->email->send())
                        {
                            echo "Your Mail send";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
                        }
                }

                echo 'Total Results: ' . $query->num_rows();





        }
    }

?>
```